# Encode the string using stream api

Tags: java, java-stream

I am looking for solution using stream api for below requirement.  basically we need to write a encryption logic to convert a string

aaabbbbaae --> a3b4a2e1

Solution without stream's api :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    String sampleString = "aaabbbaaaaaee";
    
    char charters[] = sampleString.toCharArray();
    char currentChar = charters[0];
    char prevChar = charters[0];
    int count = 0;
    String str = "";
    for (char c : charters) {
        if(c==currentChar) {
            count++;
            prevChar = c;
        }
        else {
            str = str + prevChar + count;
            currentChar = c;
            count=1;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(str+currentChar+count);
}
```

Comment: Have you already tried something or did you just dump your homework assignment here?

Comment: Not a Stream solution but convenient: `String result = Pattern.compile("(.)\\1*") .matcher(sampleString) .replaceAll(mr -> "" + mr.group().charAt(0) + (mr.end() - mr.start()));`. Requires Java 9.

Answer (score 1):

This would be pretty easy to do yourself

```
String encryptToLettersAndNumbers(String input) {
    String product = "";
    char last = input.charAt(0);
    int streak = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        if(input.charAt(i) == last) {
            streak++;
        } else {
            product = product + last + streak;
            streak = 1;
            last = input.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    product = product + last + streak;
    return product;
}
```

Note that this code is untested. Furthermore this will be a very unsafe method of encryption because h1e1l2o1 is pretty easy to guess.

Comment: as I said.  I am looking for solution using stream's api.. is that possible ?

Comment: I don't think spoonfeeding homework solutions to people who never attempted anything at all. Nevertheless, this is a good and working solution, despite OP asking for a solution with java streams (for whatever reasons).

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started-

```
String sampleString = "aaabbbaaaaaee";

Arrays.asList(sampleString.chars().mapToObj(c->(char)c).toArray(Character[]::new)).stream().forEach(c->{
    //You can put your logic here to process
    System.out.print(c);
});
```

This will convert your String to a Character list and stream through it.

Comment: Well, you're iterating twice, which is unnecessary. Just `sampleString.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c).forEach(...)` is fine.

Comment: Because it's a primitive type this would only leave you with an int pipeline, converting to an Object wrapper Character would make this iterable as intended. Unless I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: Just using `sampleString.chars().mapToObj(c->(char)c).forEach(c->{ /* whatever */ });` would achieve the same. There is no point in creating a `Character[]` array, just to pass it to `Arrays.asList(…).stream()` (which by the way, could be simplified to `Arrays.stream(…)` in the first place, but here, it’s obsolete anyway).